# asp.NET Telerik RadGrid - Page Size filter Bug/not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, telerik

I have a ajax based telerik Radgrid that works fine but the Page Size part.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="radAjaxPanel">
```

When I try to change the page size then it completely disappears, inspecting the html, this is the only code I get:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_MainBaseContentArea_MainContentArea_radGridTrafficSourcesOverview" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default">
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainBaseContentArea_MainContentArea_radGridTrafficSourcesOverview_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_ctl00_MainBaseContentArea_MainContentArea_radGridTrafficSourcesOverview_ClientState" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

This is the code to call the RadGrid:

```
    <div class="statisticsSection">
    <h2>Stats</h2>
    <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="radGridContentOverview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanged="radGridContentOverview_PageIndexChanged" >
        <MasterTableView>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Text" DataField="PagePath" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Visitors" DataField="PageViews" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="% Visitors" DataField="PageViewsPercentage" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}%" />                            
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
```

Any clue?
Tnx in advance

Comment: you mean the pager bar disappears?

Comment: no, I mean everything disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable paging with the RadGrid you should use the `OnNeedDataSource` event:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" ...>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    //get the datasource object from the database
    DataTable table = GetSomeData();

    //set the datasource - no need to call DataBind()
    RadGrid1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above the `<MasterTableView>` add the below:

```
 <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" />
```

Comment: This just keeps the Pager always on, it does not solve my problem